# dynamic combobox and select particular item in combobox to execute certain things

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a string array which contains filenames.  a number of filenames vary depending on what endusers select.  I would like know how to populate the string array onto combobox.  Thanks for your help in advance,

Comment: take a look at this post [Adding string array to combo box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123822/adding-string-array-to-combo-box)

Comment: Please read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the Help Center.

Comment: I should diligently look for exisitng questions related to my issues.  Sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is simple. Create an `ObservableCollection<string>` named `Items` and fill it with your filenames:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); } }
}
```

Make sure that you implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) correctly in the class that has the property. Next, simply data bind this property to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property in XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Finally, ensure that you have set the `DataContext` of the control with the XAML to an instance of the class with the property:

Either:

```
DataContext = this; // if properties are defined in code behind
```

Or:

```
DataContext = new ClassWithProperty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple way to achieve this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            string[] files = new string[]{};
            ObservableCollection<string> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
            comboBox1.ItemsSource = observableCollection; 

        }




    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,  it works also.  Again, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have your full array of filenames, you may want to try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myStringArray.Length; i++)
{
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(myStringArray[i]);
}
```

This should add all of the filenames into the combobox `ComboBox1`.